# Showing that $(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)=(c^2-u^2)(v^2-c^2)$, where $u=a+b$ and $v=a-b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $x=(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)$ where $a,b,c$ are real numbers, and if $u=a+b$ and $v=a-b$, then it follows that $x$ is equal to
>   $(c^2 - u^2)(v^2-c^2)$.

Help me solve this.

I put in the $u$'s and $v$'s and first get $(u+c)(u-c)$ which is $u^2-c^2$, but then it says "stop" mentally. How do I replace the third paranthesis with $u$ or $v$?

Answer (score 2):

$$(a+b+c)(a+b-c)=(a+b)^2-c^2$$

$$(b+c-a)(c+a-b)=(c+a-b)(c-(a-b))=c^2-(a-b)^2$$

Comment: @Downvoter, do you notice any mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

$$x=(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)=$$

$$((a+b)+c)((a+b)-c)(c-(a-b))(c+(a-b))=$$

$$(u+c)(u-c)(c-v)(c+v)=$$

$$(u^2-c^2)(c^2-v^2)=$$

$$(c^2-u^2)(v^2-c^2)$$